# Using ReceivedTime in Outlook VBA to count yesterday's mail

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I want to flash up a message box with the amount of mail received yesterday.

The code I have at the moment is:

```
Public Sub YesterdayCount()

Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set outNS = outApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Dim Items As Outlook.Items
Dim MailItem As Object

Dim yestcount As Integer
yestcount = 0

Set Folder = outNS.Folders("Correspondence Debt Advisor Queries").Folders("Inbox")
Set Items = Folder.Items

For Each Item In Items
    If MailItem.ReceivedTime = (Date - 1) Then
        yestcount = yestcount + 1
    End If
Next

MsgBox yestcount

End Sub
```

The problem is with the line:

```
If MailItem.ReceivedTime = (Date - 1) Then
```

The error says that an object variable is not set, but I can't fathom this after researching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost got it. You basically never set the `MailItem` nor qualified it to the `Item`, and since `ReceivedTime` is Date / Time format, it will never equal a straight `Date`.

See the code below. I added some features to sort by `ReceivedTime`, then Exit the loop once it passes yesterday's date. I also cleaned up some of the variable naming so it will not be confused with inherent Outlook Object naming conventions.

```
Public Sub YesterdayCount()

Dim outNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Set outNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Dim olFolder As Outlook.Folder
Set olFolder = outNS.Folders("Correspondence Debt Advisor Queries").Folders("Inbox")

Dim olItems As Outlook.Items
Set olItems = olFolder.Items

olItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True

Dim yestcount As Integer
yestcount = 0

Dim item As Object

For Each item In olItems

    'commented code works for MailItems
    'Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    'Set olMail = item

    Dim dRT As Date
    'dRT = olMail.ReceivedTime
    dRT = item.ReceivedTime

    If dRT < Date And dRT > Date - 2 Then
        If dRT < Date - 1 Then Exit For
        yestcount = yestcount + 1
    End If


Next

MsgBox yestcount

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Unfortunately this throws a 'type mismatch' error on the line: Set olMail = item

Comment: @ChrisWakefield - sorry to hear that. Are you running this directly in Outlook? Did you copy the code exactly as I wrote it? Do you have any other items in the `Inbox` besides `MailItems`?I just rested on my end again and it works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just have emails in the inbox, nothing else is in it. I copied it into a new module in outlook and hit run. Nor sure why the error is coming up if it works for you. I'll have a play around with it.

Comment: @ChrisWakefield - in **Outlook VBE>Tools>References** I have the following checked -> `1) Visual Basic for Applications 2) Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library 3) OLE Automation 4) Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library.` These are pretty standard, but thought it was worth having you consider / check on yours.

Comment: Just checked and I have the same as you. Not sure what the eroor could be if it's working at your end.

Comment: I've found the issue! I do have other items in the mailbox. There are some emails come through from InfoPath forms, and these have a different icon to the mail. I've tested your code on a subfolder and it works fine. Do you know how I would get it to count everything in that folder? Thanks again for all your help, I'm very new to this.

Comment: @ChrisWakefield - see my edit. just pull the `ReceivedTime` straight from the `item` object itself. By not defining the `item` as any particular type any type of item (mail, InfoPath form, calendar item, etc.) will pass through.

Comment: Thanks for your edits. Unfortunaly the code is now throwing an error 'object doesn't support this property or method' on the line: dRT = item.ReceivedTime. Sorry to be a pain, and thanks for your help

Comment: @ChrisWakefield - what is the item type it fails on? You can use `If TypeOf item is MailItem Then` to test against items that may fail. It's possible that `ReceivedTime` may not be available for all items.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, the offending items were four read receipts that were in the inbox. I deleted those and it works a charm. Thanks for your patience and your support!

Answer (score 0):

format dates before comparing:

For Each Item In Items
If format(Item.ReceivedTime,"yyyyMMdd") = format(Date - 1,"yyyyMMdd") Then
yestcount = yestcount + 1
End If
Next